# Get result of raw SQL query in Laravel 5 Eloquent

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I need help to build a Laravel query from my raw SQL Query. I tried many way and did not find my Luck. Can anybody help me? My Raw SQL code is given bellow.

```
SELECT exams. * , count( question_details.exam_id ) AS qus_enter
FROM exams
INNER JOIN question_details ON exams.id = question_details.exam_id GROUP BY exams.id
```

This is what I've tried:

```
$examListsID = DB::table('exams')
                 ->join('question_details', function($join) {
                     $join->on('exams.id', '=', 'question_details.exam_id as qus_enter');
                 })
                 ->whereraw('count(qus_enter) = exams.total_question')
                 ->select('exams.id as examID','qus_enter','exams.total_question')
                 ->count('qus_enter')
                 ->groupby('exams.id')
                 ->get();

$examLists = Addexam::where('id','=',$examListsID->examID)
```

And I Get this Error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as `qus_enter` where count(qus_enter) = exams.total_question' at line 1 (SQL: select count(`qus_enter`) as aggregate from `exams` inner join `question_details` on `exams`.`id` = `question_details`.`exam_id` as `qus_enter` where count(qus_enter) = exams.total_question)

Comment: Then please show us what you actually tried

Comment: I have two table one is 'exams' and 'question_details'. in my 'exams' table i set the total question of that exam and in my 'question_details' I entered the questions with 'exam_id'. 
I want to load only that exam which have all question inserted in 'question_details' table.

Comment: I mean I want you to update your answer with the Laravel query code (even if it's not working)

Comment: $examListsID = DB::table('exams')


            ->join('question_details', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('exams.id', '=', 'question_details.exam_id as qus_enter');


            })


            ->whereraw('count(qus_enter) = exams.total_question')
            ->select('exams.id as examID','qus_enter','exams.total_question')
            ->count('qus_enter')
            ->groupby('exams.id')
            ->get();
        $examLists = Addexam::where('id','=',$examListsID->examID);

Comment: For the next time, please *edit* your question to add details. I've done that now for you...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76859/discussion-between-shahadat-hossain-and-lukasgeiter).

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = DB::table('exams')->join('question_details','exams.id','=','question_details.exam_id')->select([
  exams.*,
  DB::raw('count( question_details.exam_id ) AS qus_enter')
])->GroupBy('exams.id')->get()
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::listen(function ($data) { 
var_dump($data->bindings);
    dd($data->sql);
});
```

Comment: Welcome. Can you offer an explanation of what you are doing here? That will help future readers with similar problems, but who may be unfamiliar with this syntax.